# How to fix compression error when repackaging Spring Boot Jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

I need to inject static UI files into an existing Spring Boot executable jar.  To do so, I'm pulling the jar as a dependency, and using the maven antrun plugin to:

- Unzip the jar in a temp dir
- Add a resources dir to the unzipped jar
- Copy static UI files to the resources dir
- Re-zip the jar

  ```
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>build-ui-kit</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <descriptors>
             <descriptor>ui-assembly-config.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.6</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>repack</id>
         <phase>compile</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <target>
             <!-- unzip jar -->
             <unzip src="${com.xxx:xxx:jar}" dest="${project.build.directory}/tmp"/>
             <!-- make resources dir in unzipped jar dir -->
             <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/tmp/resources"/>
             <!-- copy ui files to resources dir -->
             <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/tmp/resources">
               <fileset dir="${basedir}/../../src/ui/dist">
                 <include name="*"/>
               </fileset>
             </copy>
             <!-- zip tmp dir to create txapps jar  -->
             <zip basedir="${project.build.directory}/tmp" destfile="${project.build.directory}/yyyy.jar"/>
           </target>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
  ```

This all seems to work; however, when I run the Jar, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file

When I inspect the contents of the Jar, everything looks fine (the libs do not seem to be compressed).  Any idea of what's going on here or suggestions for a better repackaging solution?  Thanks!

Comment: *inject static UI files* It sounds like you're using an approach that doesn't make any sense. Why are these files not being included when the jar is built in the first place, and if they're variable, why are they not provided as a "sidecar" runtime resource?

Comment: In production, the app does not provide a UI.  I'm adding a debug UI for developers.  The UI files are not variable, but the cannot be added when the Jar is built.  When I add the files manually with 7-zip, everything works and Spring serves the UI.  There has to be an easy way to automate the process.

Comment: So just disable the UI controller with a profile or Boot configuration property. Deploying non-identical artifacts in different environments is begging for difficult-to-diagnose bugs.

Comment: the error message sounds quite comprehensive! How did you : "Re-zip the jar" ? ;)

Comment: ok, got it: the best maven-like solution 'd be: you manage the lib yourself! (as a standalone/module maven project: you extract/clone the sources, enrich with your resources, and `mvn install` it (locally, `mvn deploy` for your (company) repo) ..and let your spring-boot app depend on that module/artifact/project.

Comment: So there exists a build of your `I need to inject static UI files into an existing Spring Boot executable jar.` spring boot app... so why not changing that build and add the file there... What is the problem exactly and why modifying a spring-boot jar after building?

Comment: Yes I agree with all comments.  Usually, it would make sense to add the UI when building the Jar.  In this case I do not have that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the exec-maven-plugin and Java jar utility to add the UI files.  See code below (the ui files are in the /tmp/resources directory):

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>update-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>jar</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
          <argument>uf</argument>
          <argument>dependencies/myjar-${version}.jar</argument>
          <argument>resources</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```